# SQL using the result of a UNION query in another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

How can I complete this query?

Right now, the query I have working is this, but it is not producing the right data.

```
SELECT date, coalesce(count,0) AS count 
FROM 
    generate_series(
        '2014-12-13 12:00:00'::timestamp, 
        '2015-01-06 11:00:00'::timestamp, 
        '1 hour'::interval
    ) AS date 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            date_trunc('day', TABLE1.created_at) as day, 
            count(DISTINCT TABLE1.user) as count 
        FROM TABLE1 
        WHERE org_id = 1 
        GROUP BY day
    ) results ON (date = results.day);
```

Instead of TABLE1, I need to feed the query with data from another query which looks like this:

```
SELECT TABLE2.user_a as userid, TABLE2.created_at as createdat from TABLE2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TABLE3.user_b as userid, TABLE3.created_at as createdat from TABLE3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TABLE4.sender as userid, TABLE4.created_at as createdat from TABLE4;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: Why can't you just make your `UNION` query a subsubquery?  You ought to be able to insert it as a subquery in the `FROM` clause of the subquery you already have.

Comment: @AirThomas version is psql (8.4.22)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am actually fairly new at this, and couldn't get to something that is working

Comment: Then it looks like you could use a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any part of a `select` query that receives a table (e.g., a `from` clause, a `join` clause, etc) can receive a query surrounded in parenthesis - this is called a subquery. Note that in Postgres this subquery **must** be given an alias (i.e., a name that it can be referenced by). So in your case:

```
SELECT date, coalesce(count,0) AS count 
FROM 
    generate_series(
        '2014-12-13 12:00:00'::timestamp, 
        '2015-01-06 11:00:00'::timestamp, 
        '1 hour'::interval
    ) AS date 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            date_trunc('day', subquery.created_at) as day, 
            count(DISTINCT subquery.user) as count 
              -- Subquery here:
        FROM (SELECT TABLE2.user_a as userid, TABLE2.created_at as createdat from TABLE2 
              UNION ALL 
              SELECT TABLE3.user_b as userid, TABLE3.created_at as createdat from TABLE3 
              UNION ALL 
              SELECT TABLE4.sender as userid, TABLE4.created_at as createdat from TABLE4) 
             subquery 
        WHERE org_id = 1 
        GROUP BY day
    ) results ON (date = results.day);
```

Comment: Alright have it working as per the last comment on the first post, but tested this as well and it worked too. Thanks